# Replacing "infinite" with "finite" of a statement

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> **Statement:** The intersection of a finite collection of open subsets of $R^n$ is open in $R^n$.

---

Proof of the statement:

Suppose that $\mathcal{O}=\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}\mathcal{O}_i$ for some $k$, where $\mathcal{O}_i$ is open in $R^n$. Let ${\bf u}$ be a member of $\mathcal{O}$. If $1\leq i\leq k$, ${\bf u}$ belongs to $\mathcal{O}_i$ and $\mathcal{O}_i$ is open in $R^n$, so there is a positive number $r_i$ such that $\mathcal{B}_{r_i}({\bf u})\subseteq\mathcal{O}_i$. Define $r=\min\{r_1,\cdots,r_k\}$. Then $r$ is positive, and the open ball about the point $u$, $\mathcal{B}_r({\bf u})$, is contained in each $\mathcal{O}_i$ and therefore is contained in the intersection $\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}\mathcal{O}_i=\mathcal{O}$. Thus ${\bf u}$ is an interior point of $\mathcal{O}$. Therefore, every point in $\mathcal{O}$ is an interior point of $\mathcal{O}$, so $\mathcal{O}$ is open in $R^n$.

---

Now, if I replace "finite" with "infinite", the sentence "Then $r$ is positive, and the open ball about the point $u$, $\mathcal{B}_r({\bf u})$, is contained in each $\mathcal{O}_i$.........."  will be wrong. Because there are infinite many balls and we choose $r$ be the minimum radius, there must exists a ball that contain an element that lies on the boundary, so the intersection of a finite collection of open subsets of $R^n$ is closed in $R^n$.

---

Can someone check my logic? If not right, please point me out where I do wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not necessarily a minimum to an infinite set of numbers. What if the set of balls is $\{A_n\}$ where $A_n=B_{1+1/n}(u)$? The radii of the balls are $\{2,3/2,4/3,5/4,...\}$. There is no minimum.

Also be careful with open and closed sets. If a set in $\mathbb R^n$ contains an element of its boundary, it is not open. But that does not mean that it is closed. A set is closed if its complement is open.

The phrase

> there must exists a ball that contain an element that lies on the boundary

doesn't make much sense. You should make this statement precise. In doing so, you may find that what you mean to say is not actually true.

Finally, note that an infinite intersection of open sets *could* be open, it just doesn't *have* to be.

Comment: If $n$ approaches to infinity, $1+1/n=1$, why $1$ is exclusive?

Comment: If $1+1/n=1$, then $1/n=0$. What number could $n$ possibly be?

Comment: I forget that infinity isn't a number. The radius just getting smaller.

Answer (score 0):

The first proof is correct, the second one not. Consider $A_n=\left(0,1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$, than $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n=(0,1]$ is neither open nor closed.